# How to connect to port immedeately, avoiding socket_bind(): unable to bind address?

Tags: tcp, socket

When running a code that is supposed to read from a TCP/IP port I often get the following message (depending exactly what language have been used):

```
socket_bind(): unable to bind address
```

I know that this happens when some other process listens to this port / is binded to this port (I do not know the exact phrase to describe), and therefore my code cannot listen to that port. However, it is *my code* which I just stopped (by CTRL-C) that is blocking this port! There seem to be some timeout involved, and after waiting some time (about 30 seconds) I can start my code to listen on this specific port without problems.

I would like to know:

- Why is the port still blocked although I have stopped the code?
- How can I force the system to release this port so I can restart my code and start listening to this port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're talking C/C++, use `setsockopt()` and `SO_REUSEADDR`. This allows reuse as long as there is no active process listening to that port.

Edit: The reason it is still in use is you didn't close the socket down appropriately. You Control-C killed it. You can use `netstat` to see the ports that are open or not quite closed yet.

http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/setsockoptman.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207781/error-in-binding-port-address-already-in-use-tcp-socket-programming-in-unix

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071107/rebinding-a-port-to-datagram-socket-on-a-difftent-ip

Comment: Thank you very much. Although it is php and/or python, I can look for the corresponding option now.